# I am confusing the shape of series and dataframe

Tags: python

I am just starting to learn python.
I wonder why df if dataframe, not series? Is because it has a column name?
If yes, is it series if the code would be `df = pd.series(['1','2','3'])` ?

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'col_str': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']})
```

Comment: `df` is the name of the variable in the code you provided. You can call it whatever you want, what defines the type of object (DataFrame or Series), is what's on the right of the `=` sign. In this case, it's a DataFrame. If you wrote `df = pd.Series(...`, it would be a Series. Also, the import of `numpy` is unnecessary in the example.

Comment: If you're just starting out learning Python, it would probably be better to do basic tutorials on Python itself before trying to pick up a complex third-party package like Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df` is just the name you chose for your DataFrame, as you did in the last line. Many people use `df` as a naming convention, since it stands for **D**ata**F**rame. But it has no special meaning within Python.

You can definitely define `df` to be a Series with:

```
df = pd.series(['1','2','3'])
```

But I wouldn't advise to do so, because it's confusing, and hurts code readability. In the same way, I could define variables like this to confuse the reader, but it would still be valid:

```
number = 'some string that is not a number'
string = 9
```

Anyway, you could also choose some other name that is more clear to you for your DataFrame, such as:

```
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'col_str': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']})
```

Finally, and for completeness, a Pandas DataFrame is, in general, composed out of `pd.Series`. And a DataFrame with only one Series could look really similar to a Series, but it is not, as the DataFrame is another Python class (that potentially contains Series), has different methods than the Series class, etc.

You can always extract the Series from the DataFrame and operate on it as a Series, or you can operate indirectly on the Series within the DataFrame with DataFrame operations.